# d3.js nested selection with 2d array

Tags: d3.js

Say I have the following JSON array:

```
var json = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3]
];
```

How can I render a grid of SVG `rect` nodes without performing 2 `selectAll` calls?  In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQSm8/) I was able to make the grid, but I had to render each row inside of an intermediate `g` node.  Is there a way to write it without the first selection?  If I try:

```
svg.data(json)
    .selectAll('rect')
        .data(function(data) { return data; })
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', function(data, x, y) {
            return (x * size) + (x * spacing);
        })
        .attr('y', function(data, x, y) {
            return (y * size) + (y * spacing);
        })
        .attr('width', size)
        .attr('height', size);
```

it only renders the first row of the 2D array.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use `selectAll` twice?

Comment: Your SVG structure should closely reflect your JSON structure. If you want to change the SVG structure to not have g elements then you need to change your JSON structure (probably into a flat array).

Comment: @Quinn not really, I'm new to d3 so I was just trying to better understand the APIs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you'd rather not have the `g` nodes in the hierarchy, and instead, you want to make all the `rects` direct siblings?

This is doable, but you have to first flatten the json into a 1-dimensional array with 9 elements (not shown here; can use `Array.reduce()`). Then you would only select and bind once:

```
var flatJson = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
svg
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(flatJson)`
```

and position based on `i`:

```
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', function(d, i) {
    return (i % numColumns) * (size + spacing);
  })
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return Math.floor(i/numColumns) * (size + spacing);
  })
  .attr('width', size)
  .attr('height', size);
```

The trade off is that there needs to be a sense of the number of columns `numColumns = 3`.

The flattened json could be turned into an array of objects, and each object could have a column and row. For eample:

```
var flatJson = [
  { row:0, col:0, value: 1},
  { row:0, col:1, value: 2},
  { row:0, col:2, value: 3},
  { row:1, col:0, value: 1},
  ...
]
```